# Viewer is not a constructor of ROS3D

Tags: ros3djs, robotwebtools

I tried to implement a URDF viewer on web using React as front end and Flask as back end. ROSLIB and ROS3D was installed using npm. While running the script, React complaint that Viewer is not a constructor of ROS3D.